# How to create update trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a very simple question, so I hope someone will help.

I have a MySQL table with ID and CREDIT. I want to do an update trigger, which would change the update value if credit is 0. So something like "if old.CREDIT = 0 then new.CREDIT = 0.001". So what will be the syntax of the trigger? Thanks.

Comment: is google broken? First hit in a 10 second search: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: @MitchWheat: That took 10 seconds?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [***tutorial on MySQL Triggers***](http://web.archive.org/web/20061122063729/http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers) which gives simple to complex examples.
Here is a simple example on `before update` trigger, that may help you.

Assuming table name as `credit_info`.

```
delimiter //
create trigger sample_trigger_before_update_on_credit_info before update on test.credit_info
  for each row begin
    if new.credit = 0 then
      set new.credit = 0.001;
    end if;
  end;
//
delimiter ;
```

Let us say, table have 2 records as follows:

```
+------+--------+
| id   | credit |
+------+--------+
|    1 |  1.000 |
|    2 |  3.000 |
+------+--------+
```

When you issue an update statement as:

```
update credit_info set credit=0 where id=2;
```

The resulting record would be as follows:

```
+------+--------+
| id   | credit |
+------+--------+
|    2 |  0.001 |
+------+--------+
```

Let me hope, sample example will accelerate your energies.